# Future supervisor changes author order before submitting grant application

Tags: academia, authorship

In 2020, I started to work on a grant proposal for a 2-year postdoc. After 2 months, I was told by my prospective supervisor that the proposal was so good, that it could become a 3-year project and give a grant to a PhD student. I accepted, allowing my prospective supervisor to act as the principal investigator of the project. 3 days before submitting, without my consent, my prospective supervisor put his name as first-author of the proposal, in the version "Final 3", but I wrote at least 75% of it.

And there are 4 letters attached to the proposal by external advisors that report my name first. Is this a case of plagiarism? Or has it a different name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plagiarism is not against the law; fraud, perjury and copyright infringement are. To determine whether anything illegal transpired, we would need much more information. However, we may be able to short-circuit the inquiry by asking whether the changes made are *required* in order to submit the grant proposal. As a general rule, the National Science Foundation (a major source of multi-year postdoctoral funding) distinguishes between a PI and "other staff", and sponsoring universities generally require an affiliation with the university in order to be a PI. Hence a faculty member essentially serves as a conduit for a student's (or recent graduate) application for a grant.

There is no legal significance to the order of names in terms of copyright – that is not a copyright-protected characteristic. Order of names is not a true or false statement that is covered by perjury law, nor does it imply anything false from which a charge of fraud could be sustained (e.g. it does not imply that X wrote most or even *any* part of a proposal, and authorship of a proposal is not a material matter in inducing a granting agency to hand over money – rather, they rely on the logical properties of the proposal including the qualifications of those involved).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I agree with your observations. Indeed the authorship of a proposal is not a material matter in inducing a granting agency to hand over money. However that is true that, to help a PhD student fund her studies, I handed over my project in the hand of a person who, as soon as he had the rights to do so, started changing my project. That was part of the risk, but now, to a person who is judging whether to hire me for a new job, being able to prove that I was the main contributor to a winning proposal, is something important. Legally, right now, I am not.

Comment: The case in Austria that happened to me was similar to the example of the National Science Foundation. However you report that the the fund distinguishes between PI and "other staff", so my question would be: if is the student/recent graduate to write the application and plan the project, is the eventual PI in the right to consider him/herself as the main author of the proposal? I think I was treated very bad, that my supervisor took advantage of me to just add one more trophy to his/her list of projects. And I am now left with just the opportunity to execute what s/he says, or nothing at all.

Comment: Well, in those cases where I was PI, I knew very well that the student was the author of the proposal. However, I do list those grants on my CV (along with the recipient's name), and that is standard in my profession. But yes, you do run a risk, though the university and the NSF have final say.  I'm not familiar with the details of Austria, and you would probably get more useful guidance as to policy usual on Academia SE.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's a big deal. I would just ask if you can be first author again. What's the risk other than getting your supervisor upset and not graduating with a PhD.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).